# Conflicting table names with laravel

Tags: sqlite, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to set up my tables and wasn't getting my data into the table and tried doing `DB:table('tableName')->insert($variable);`

I already had a migration for `tableName` and thought I was inserting data into this migration, but in fact it seems to have created a different table with the same name.

So now when I try to run `php artisan migrate` I get errors. I've looked into the sqlite database and I don't see a duplicate table.

I can't find how to fix this error. I've run every migrate command to try and go back but nothing works.

Errors:

`[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 table "regions" already exists (SQL: create table "regions" ("id" integer not null primary key autoincrement, "user_id" integer not null, "start" float not null, "end" float not null, "data" text not null, "created_at" datetime null, "updated_at" datetime null, "remember_token" varchar null, foreign key("user_id") references "users"("id") on delete cascade))`


 `[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 table "regions" already exists`

Comment: Delete the table manually and then run `artisan migrate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to fix this I had to

1. rename my migration table name (this the original one)
2. enter the sqlite db from command line. (i can now see the conflicting table, I could not before)
3. drop the regions table (the table causing the name conflict)
4. change migration table name back. (in my editor, not from the command line)
5. enter sqlite db again and rename the changed table name (this is the original one associated w/ my migration) back to the original name.
6. run artisan:refresh

edited to add more details

Answer (score 1):

You need to go in and manually delete that table (and/or the 'other' table with the same name.

Then re-run the migration and it will populate accordingly.  After that you should be able to run the following to 'update' tables you change through your migration files:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

To add things to the table manually after you have the tables setup - try using seeds:

```
php artisan db:seed
```

Comment: Thanks. This was accurate, however if you read my answer I just added, I could not see this conflicting table in my db. Only one name showed up so I had to do a couple extra steps.